# Writing to an external file using ACCESS 97

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using classic VBA and I'm having problems creating an external file. 
Bassically using a table I want to create a standard txt file. 
I already found a way to check if the file exists and kill it.

```
If Dir("%USERPROFILE%\Documents\iMacros\Macros\CriarGDC.iim") <> "" Then
    Kill "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\iMacros\Macros\CriarGDC.iim"
    Else
    End If
```

and also a way to write all the lines I need

```
Open "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\iMacros\Macros\CriarGDC.iim" For Append As #1
    Print #1, "1100258698,4"
Close #1
```

and also found a way to launch firefox with the imacros file

Problem IS:

I CANNOT CREATE the file. 
I tried using

```
Shell ("cmd.exe")
SendKeys ("dir /s/b %USERPROFILE%\Documents\iMacros\Macros\*.itwontfindanything > %USERPROFILE%\Documents\iMacros\Macros\CriarGDC.iim")
```

But I'm having some permissions problems - windows 7 won't allow me to do that. 
A lot of people told me that the command

```
Sub WriteFile(ByVal FileName As String, ByVal Contexto As String)
  Dim fnum%
  fnum = FreeFile()
  Open FileName For Output As fnum
  Print #fnum, Contexto
Close #fnum
End Sub
```

Should work, but it just doesn't!
Erm... 
Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When giving your *WriteFile* procedure a *FileName* which includes an environment variable (such as "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\foo.txt"), VBA gives me error #76, '*Path not found*".

Use the *Environ()* function to resolve your environment variable before you give it to *WriteFile*.

```
WriteFile Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\iMacros\Macros\CriarGDC.iim", "some text"
```